# Can't stop local node server with Ctrl + C (Mac)

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I have never had this problem when developing node server locally. It may have started after updating xCode.

I tried with the simplest code

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000', '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
 console.log("Exiting...");
 process.exit();
});
```

but can't observe any log when I try Ctr+C to quit.

**UPDATE**
When I tried pressing and holding 3-4 seconds it worked ..weird because pressing 10-20 times without holding didn't work

```
App listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc^CExiting...
```

Comment: Surely that's not the only code you have in your script... You should post a minimal, reproducible example instead. It's quite possible you have something that is keeping the event loop too busy and node is not able to process the key press.

Comment: If you can't stop it, then presumably something else is trapping it. Does a trivial program with a `setTimeout()` call to keep it stalled open stop properly?

Comment: I tried running only express but nothing else and still have the same problem. It was not like this a couple of days ago. Updating XCode may have introduced this

Comment: Xcode shouldn't affect your terminal. I think your terminal settings have changed for unrelated reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're using OSX, type `Ctrl+C` instead of `Cmd+C`.

Comment: It didn't work thanks. `App listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000 
ccccccccccc`

Comment: Good point. Control+C is `^C` which is the break. Command-C is for copying text.

Comment: Are you sure your control key works properly? It's an infrequently used button. It can also be remapped in the System Preferences.

Comment: Can you describe the steps to remap the Control key?

Comment: Open System Preferences, under Keyboard choose the "Modifier Keys" button.

Comment: @tadman thanks a lot it seems to be working after resetting to defaults even though it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Sometimes computers are just plain confusing. Glad you could fix it!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Pat Needham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133299/8963597), Also check Apple Logo > System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.
If you enable any unchecked item and enter `ctrl+c`, then it will show which one has also `ctrl+c`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had this line in my code:

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
```

I had this in my code so I could read global hotkeys, but forgot I left it there. Removing it or setting raw mode to false allowed nodejs to properly catch sigint again.