# How to exit a Node program gracefully when ended manually (Ctrl+C, kill command, etc.)?

Tags: node.js

I want my Node program to perform some tasks (eg. closing down the database connection and deleting some objects) before exiting, even when the program is stopped manually (via Ctrl+C or the `kill` command for example). Is this possible?

I've tried using `process.on('exit')` and `process.on('SIGINT')`, but my tasks never finish before the program exits and I'm not sure whether this handles the `kill` command too:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const log = require('./middleware/log')
const error = require('./middleware/error')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const cleanup = require('./middleware/cleanup');

(async () => {

  // handle Ctrl+C
  process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    cleanup(browser) // this never finishes before the program ends
    process.exit(2)
  })

  // log program exit
  process.on('exit', (code) => {
    if (code === 2) {
      log('Program exited manually.')
    } else if (code === 1) {
      log('Program crashed.')
    } else {
      log('Program exited.')
    }
    cleanup(browser) // I've tried putting it here too, but it still doesn't finish before the program ends
    process.exit(code)
  })

  await mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://app:' + process.env.MONGO_PW_DEV + '@' + process.env.MONGO_IP_DEV + ':' + process.env.MONGO_PORT_DEV + '/' + process.env.MONGO_DB_DEV,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  )

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
  page = await browser.newPage()

  // do stuff

  cleanup(browser)

})().catch(async (err) => {
  cleanup(browser)
  error(err)
})
```

Here is my cleanup function:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

module.exports = (browser) => {
  mongoose.disconnect()
    .then(res => {
      browser.close()
        .then(res => {
          return
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doing a cleanup action just before node.js exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits)

Comment: paste your sample program, this will make more clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @Sohan OP is asking about how to gracefully end when the program is killed (or if it is at least possible). This is not about debugging.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I have tried that but the program always ends before the tasks in `process.on('exit')` can finish.

Comment: What are the possible way you have tried please highlight those.

Comment: @Sohan I edited my question to include what I've tried. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Graceful shutdown in NodeJS, handling using `kill signal`

> A signal is an asynchronous notification sent to a process or to a
>   specific thread to notify an event that occurred.

[See more about Node.js Signal Events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events)

When the NodeJS process receives a signal, signal events will be emitted
e.g. 'SIGINT', 'SIGTERM', etc.

- 'SIGINT' generated with +C in the terminal.
- The 'SIGTERM' signal is a generic signal used to cause program termination. Unlike 'SIGKILL', this signal can be blocked, handled, and ignored. It is the normal way to politely ask a program to terminate.
- The shell command kill generates 'SIGTERM' by default.

[More about Termination Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)

We just need to add handler to receive 'SIGTERM' signal:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Signal received.');
});
```

In your case, I think process events might help

Moreover for the normal case, for listening to the exit event and set the program to perform other tasks, `process` can emit events such as `beforeExit` or `exit`

[See 'process' events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_events)

> **Event: 'exit'** The 'exit' event is emitted when the Node.js process is
>   about to exit as a result of either:
>
> - The process.exit() method being called explicitly;
> - The Node.js event loop no longer having any additional work to perform.
>
> There is no way to prevent the exiting of the event loop at this
>   point, and once all 'exit' listeners have finished running the Node.js
>   process will terminate.

Hope it help! :)

[More about Graceful shutdown in NodeJS](https://hackernoon.com/graceful-shutdown-in-nodejs-2f8f59d1c357)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I didn't know that SIGTERM would be emitted by the `kill` command. My problem though, is that even if I use these event listeners, the tasks are never able to finish before the program ends. Please see the code I added above.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared the code but you can try something like this,

```
      process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      console.info('SIGTERM signal received.');
      console.log('Closing http server.');
      expressServer.close(() => {
        console.log('Http server closed.');
        // boolean means [force], see in mongoose doc
        mongoose.connection.close(false, () => {
          console.log('MongoDb connection closed.');
          process.exit(0);
        });
      });
   });
```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my code above to show what I tried and it's pretty much what you have here. My problem is that the program always exits before the tasks (closing Express, Mongoose, etc.) finish.

Answer (score 0):

To catch Ctrl+C, ensure you've added *`process.stdin.resume()`*:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('Interrupted');
  process.exit();
});
```

**from* https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458139/2154075